# How to save instance of an activity?

Tags: android, lifecycle, android-activity

I am new going for the android.I am working on an app in which I have two activities let say A and B.
In activity A I have a list view of some items.I have a button in activity A which takes me to activity B.In activity B I have a seek-bar.

I am using the seek-bar to filter the result of activity A.

I have two buttons in activity B cancel and filter.

After adjusting seek-bar if user clicking filter button than it takes user to activity A and showing filter results.
User can play between activity A and activity B.

Now three different scenario are there for coming back from activity B to A.

1. By pressing filter button
2. By pressing cancel button
3. By pressing phone's back button

After adjusting seek-bar if user pressing filter button then activity A is re ordering and showing filter results. Here I want to save the instance of activity B. so that from activity A if user again going in activity B then I can show the previous state of activity B.(I am able to do this)

In second scenario if user adjusting the seek-bar again and pressing cancel button then Activity A is reordering.Here I do not want to save the instance of activity B and if user again going in activity B from activity A then I want to show the previous state of activity B.(I am not getting how to do this ??)

In Third scenario if user adjusting the seek-bar again and pressing phone's back button then Activity A is reordering but now if user again going in activity B from activity A then activity B is restarting that I do not want, here also I want to show the previous state of activity B.(I am not getting how to do this also ??)

I am stuck with this problem.
Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You must consider each of the cases and manage the activity lifecycle accordingly. You did this just fine, the problem is how to manage it. So, the first step is to study this:

[activity and lifecycles](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

After understanding how the lifecycle of activities is handled by the android os you're on your way: Manage the life of your second activity so that state is mantained by overriding the onPause method (which is called when your activity is no longer in the front of the application) or finish the activity if you don't want to save the state (effectively calling the onStop method.

I would solve this in this way:

- in activity A i call the activity B with a startActivityForResult. This way, when the activity B is finished, it's state is not mantained. So, call finish() inside activity B to return to activity A without saving it's state.

  - When wanting to save the state of activity b, call the activity A so that the onPause method gets called and the state saved.

Hope this clarifies it for you.

Comment: Hey.. thank you so much for reply. i have study the activity lifecycle. Still I have some confusion. i am able to save any value of activity B. but can we save the ui also means seek-bar adjustment.plz let me no how should i save the state and restore it by providing some code example. thank u so much in advance.